# Extremely large network traffic using RosLibJs - possible solutions

Tags: ros, roslibjs, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am using RosLibJs for a web GUI that shows robot data like position, battery status, map etc.

Unfortunately, it uses a **lot** of network traffic (around 20 GBytes per day!). I am thinking this is due to the direct subscriptions to topics and the high frequency the robot emits data on those topics (like at 10 Hz, for example).

Now, I am unsure how to solve this problem. I thought of 2 possible solutions, maybe you people can help me with it:

1. Create specialized nodes that only publish data when needed and not in the frequency the robot requires it internally,
2. Request data periodically from JS side and offer a service from ROS side.

Do you have other ideas? Is there maybe a simpler way?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325694/extremely-large-network-traffic-using-roslibjs---possible-solutions/) by [mneumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/37505/mneumann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-06-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-13**:
20 GB a day would seem to equal around 240 KB/sec. That is quite some traffic. Would make sense to try and figure out what contributes most to that 240 KB/sec and start from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would be a good use for a throttle node (http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/throttle). What it does is subscribe to a topic and then republishes it on "`<originaltopic>_throttle`" at a given rate or bandwidth cap. It is just a single command to run and really easy to add to a launch file. Then in your javascript web page you subscribe to the throttled topic.

---

Originally posted by [AvocadoOfDestiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/43217/avocadoofdestiny/) with karma: 26 on 2019-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mneumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/37505/mneumann/) on 2019-06-21**:
This sounds like a great solution. I will try it and let you know!